# Dictionary on multiple layers C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

everyone! Before i explain, i must say i tried to read some questions here similar to my case but couldn't get how to solve my problem, that's why i'm asking here.

Trying to put it simply, i'm working on a sort of database about Pokémon (so who knows Pokémon can understand what i'm doing) and i'm importing with json a txt file with the data i need. Until now i used a dual String dictionary structure (Dictionary   String, String) to handle all data, like

```
"2"(this is a value used to handle the list of all Pokémon, in fact 2 is for ivysaur): {
    "number": 2,
    "national": "2",
    "where_to_find": {
        "red": "-",
        "blue": "-",
        "yellow": "-",
        (and so on until shield, it's just a list of locations in every game where to find the pkmn)
    }
```

and there is also more data structured like this, just as a single String key or Dictionary (dual String) like "where_to_find" as you can see above.
At the beginning of the code i created a class to handle the keys about every index in the list (every pkmn) and stated clearly

```
        public Dictionary<String, String> where_to_find;
        public String number;
        public String national;
```

and all the rest. It works just fine. That's not the problem.
My problem is now i need to start handling the data in the txt file with a structure on multiple layers of String Keys. Since i never used such structure, i tried a simple stupid test and added in the txt file what follows (i added it at the first index, which would be Bulbasaur):

```
    "hello": {
        "hey": {
            "hi": "greeting"
        }
    }
```

and above also stated that

```
        public Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>> hello;
```

As it recognised hello (when i write pokemon.hel, it suggests "hello" for auto-compile), but didn't recognise hey or hi, i also declared hey as a Dictionary String, String and hi as String.
BUT, this way it supposes it's pokemon.hey and pokemon.hi.
To be clear to you, think of this: suppose i want to bring up:

```
   Messagebox.Show(pokemon.hello.hey.hi);
```

The messagebox in this case should write "greeting". What i can't get to do is this kind of formula, like pokemon.hello.hey.hi, or pokemon.hello["hey"["hi"]]. How can i do that? Thanks in advance for your suggestions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `hello["hey"]["hi"]`

You are using the second index ([“hi”]) on the “hey” string, that expect an Int index, you should use it outside

Comment: i tried, but when i go for ["hey"[   it suggests i should insert a int index.

Comment: You ara using the second index ([“hi”]) to the “hey” string, that expect and Int index, you should use it outside

Comment: Cause hello[“hey”] returns your dictionary where hi key is store.

Comment: oh, i read wrong, now i see. i tried as you said, with two separated [ ] [ ] and it works! thank you so much!